# Supporting interactions between browser clients and native clients

Tags: sockets, websocket, cross-platform, native

My problem is pretty simple to explain, but difficult for me to find a good overall solution for.

I want to support my multiplayer game for browsers, but I also want it to be playable on Windows, and Android (at the moment) as well. The actual problem I'm coming across is that I need a basic TCP or UDP connection to work with in order to simplify the cross-platform aspect for the clients. I'm only aware of WebSockets being a possible/viable solution for creating real-time client side apps in browsers, but that requires a WebSocket server to connect to as well.

Now, because there isn't any viable alternative to WebSockets for the browser client this would suggest the next approach would be to make/use web-socket libraries for the native clients (windows and android). At least, this was my first thought. I've come to the conclusion that this would add far too much overhead for me to handle and continue to support in the future at my skill-level and time. I have also read that the support in other languages (libraries and the like) don't fully comply to the WS standards which turns me away from the idea further.

My last thoughts have led me to two other possible solutions that both have some major downsides.

**Potential Solution 1** -- very weak overall 
The first solution I could attempt to try seems like the most obvious option at the current time, but has one issue that has some potentially huge flaws. Basically, have two servers. One that works for browser clients and one that works for native clients. The problem with this is that I'm segregating a playerbase that may or may not be small. If the playerbase is already small I'm losing out on people being able to play games with each other. The second big problem is that now if someone wants to log on to their account from either client there needs to be one universal database to pick from (that both servers can access) - and if I'd like to kick a client off from one server because someone logged on a different client it would require inter-server validating and what not. This starts to sound more and more stringy and prone to security holes the more I think about it.

**Potential Solution 2** -- strong in many ways more than 1, but has 2 big drawbacks. 
The last approach I came up with seems to be the most idealistic, but also has some terrible drawbacks I've read about in the past. If I were to have one main server that could handle interactions between the WebSocket and a UDP connection, it would mean I could have one server, not have to de-localize my database, and have players from browser and native clients. The big problem though, is that this server will be listening through two different protocols ***and*** sending through two different protocols. I'm not entirely sure how possible this is and likely to be realistically combinable in Node.JS, but I think it would be my best bet. The biggest problem I believe that comes with this approach is the mix of protocols. I've read in the past that having UDP mixed in with TCP causes UDP to drop far more often and TCP to slow down just the same. This could be mildly catastrophic in the end.

Is solution 2 as good as an approach I'm making it out to be? Or would solution 1 actually be far more advantageous. At this point, solution 1 just seems like a catastrophe waiting to happen. Are the problems I mentioned with solution 2 still present to this day, and would there be a way to work around it's problems? And would the problems associated with TCP combined with UDP be lessoned with a more "powerful" server, for lack of a better word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server should support both. WebSocket is just a transport technology, and your server logic should be transport agnostic. Your server should listen in two ports, one for raw TCP (or whatever your game use) and other for WebSocket, and the communication layer of your application should abstract this fact for your game logic.

For example, your regular web server supports HTTP and HTTPS, in two different TCP ports, but when you are writing your web app, most of the time, you do not care how each client is connecting, you just write your application logic, and the web server will handle each client transport for you.

Comment: That actually helps out a lot, and the relation to how http/s works makes me far more attracted to the idea.  I'll probably go this route, but I'm still concerned about the udp/tcp interchange problem (prone to packet loss and such). Though, I think this would be my best choice